# ReportingServices2010.FireEvent, Subscription Parameter

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report set up with a subscription that outputs a PDF to windows share. My issue is this. I need to add 1 report parameter to the report subscription and be able to have a user 'trigger' the subscription based on the parameter that they define. (Having them access the reporting services site is not an option).

My Current thinking involves writing an application in .NET that can trigger the subscription using the FireEvent method, however I have no idea how to be able to pass a parameter to a subscription this way. I have looked into other various methods within the ReportingServices2010 class but I am absolutely at a loss and have surrendered myself to the wisdom of this site.

Below is the code I am currently using which works great, but I need to either expand on it or change it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SSRSReportGenerator.SRSWebService;

namespace SSRSReportGenerator
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
        rs.Url = "http://server/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx";
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        //set report properties
        string site = "/report/report";

        // Get the subscription
        Subscription[] subs = rs.ListMySubscriptions(site);

        try
        {                
            //specify null for siteURL if native mode
            rs.FireEvent("TimedSubscription", subs[0].SubscriptionID, null);
            Console.WriteLine("Event fired.");

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Again thank you to everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to fire the schedule from a C# program, why bother with the schedule at all? Just run the report with your parameters directly from your program. It is quite easy and [Microsoft have some example code to get you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

> ```
> using System;
> using System.IO;
> using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
> using myNamespace.MyReferenceName;
>
> class Sample
> {
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
>         rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
>         rs.Url = "http://myserver/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx";
>
>         // Render arguments
>         byte[] result = null;
>         string reportPath = "/AdventureWorks Sample Reports/Employee Sales Summary";
>         string format = "MHTML";
>         string historyID = null;
>         string devInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";
>
>         // Prepare report parameter.
>         ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[3];
>         parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
>         parameters[0].Name = "EmpID";
>         parameters[0].Value = "288";
>         parameters[1] = new ParameterValue();
>         parameters[1].Name = "ReportMonth";
>         parameters[1].Value = "6"; // June
>         parameters[2] = new ParameterValue();
>         parameters[2].Name = "ReportYear";
>         parameters[2].Value = "2004";
>
>         DataSourceCredentials[] credentials = null;
>         string showHideToggle = null;
>         string encoding;
>         string mimeType;
>         string extension;
>         Warning[] warnings = null;
>         ParameterValue[] reportHistoryParameters = null;
>         string[] streamIDs = null;
>
>         ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
>         ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();
>
>         rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;
>
>         execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID);
>
>         rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us"); 
>         String SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;
>
>         Console.WriteLine("SessionID: {0}", rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID);
>
>
>         try
>         {
>             result = rs.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
>
>             execInfo = rs.GetExecutionInfo();
>
>             Console.WriteLine("Execution date and time: {0}", execInfo.ExecutionDateTime);
>
>
>         }
>         catch (SoapException e)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.OuterXml);
>         }
>         // Write the contents of the report to an MHTML file.
>         try
>         {
>             FileStream stream = File.Create("report.mht", result.Length);
>             Console.WriteLine("File created.");
>             stream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
>             Console.WriteLine("Result written to the file.");
>             stream.Close();
>         }
>         catch (Exception e)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
>         }
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: The ReportServiceExecution class did it for me! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.